# Finding the kernel of a homomorphism between non-zero complex

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Question: Prove that the mapping from $x \mapsto x^6$ from the non-zero complex to the non-zero complex is a homomorphism.

Assuming the operation is multiplication, it is trivial to see that homomorphism holds.

Here's a troublesome one:

What is the kernel of the homomorphism map?

Only Hints. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I figured if I can find a normal subgroup of the group, I should be done. But how sure can I be?

Comment: Since multiplication scales and rotates a complex number, which numbers scale and rotate to $1$?

Comment: This is basically saying when is $x^6 = 1$ where $x $ is a non-zero complex number. Do you know De Moivre's theorem? Then, expressing $1$ in it's polar form will give you the answer.

Comment: That theorem was a distant past. I'll take a look. Thanks for the illumination. This shall suffice.

Comment: (Aside remark: $(\mathbb{C}^*,\cdot)$ is abelian, hence every subgroup is normal.)

Comment: Your edit won't help much. The kernel that you are asked to find is *one particular normal subgroup*; it's not just any old normal subgroup (and, as the comment of @Cla shows, *every* subgroup is normal).